# how to extract variable names from a c,c++ code saved in a .c,.cpp file

Tags: c#, c++, regex

**Description :**

I am making a plagiarism detection application in which it reads source code submitted by students from a .c,.cpp file and extracts all the variable names to perform some actions on them.

**What have I tried :**

I have tried to use regular expression as following but id did not work

```
textBox1.Text = "int sum,a;";
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = 
 new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(
  @"^[a-zA-Z](([a-zA-Z0-9]*)|(_[a-zA-Z0-9]_*)|(_[a-zA-Z0-9]*)|([a-zA-Z0-9]_*))$");
if (regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Value is correct.");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Value is not correct.");
}
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong or at least put me in a right direction?

Comment: C++ isn´t a regular language, so stop this nonsense. If you really want the var names, use Clang or whatever; and keep in mind that the first thing someone changes in copied code are the var names.

Comment: I agree with DeviantFan - check the structure of the code using Clang, and give it a score against the other entries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if regular expressions are a good way to do what you want to do. I've only ever used them to find certain text patterns. The problem is that not every word matching your expression is a variable name, you'd have to filter keywords, string literals, constant definitions and so on.

I'd recommend parsing the code and then walking the abstract syntax tree, parse tree or whatever your parser generates.

A good example of how to do something like this is given in the ANTLR documentation. And as far as I remember they offer a C and a C++ grammar.

Answer (score -1):

There is built-in support for identifying that kind of token in P5RE syntax.  To get help on P5 regular expressions, ask some P5 programmers :)  Look at the PerlMonks website, in particular.  [Here is a reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) from the horse's mouth.  The code \w is "word character (alphanumeric and underscore).  The zero-width assertions are \b for word boundary and \B for *not* a word boundary. [Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) is a tutorial.